# If the interior $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ and the boundary $\partial A$ are connected, is $A$ a connected subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Here is what I have:  Let $A=(-\infty, 0]\cup \mathbb Q$, where $\mathbb Q$ denotes the set of rational numbers. Here $A$ is not connected. However, $\partial A=[0,+\infty)$ and $\operatorname{Int}(A)=(-\infty, 0)$ are both connected. Therefore, $A$ is not a connected subset of $X$. Does this counterexample work?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: You forgot to mention what $X$ is in this case, but I assume it's $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.